# SDK Manager - Android studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I have no access to sdk manger. There are nothing in: android studio -> tools. 5 options there, but no option 'android' or sdk manager. And also I cannot find sdkmanger.exe file in sdk folder. I'm looking for answers but I can find nothing at all. Please help.

Solved.

I've installed some previous version and its working. Don't know why...

Comment: update you android studio

Comment: update through stable channel

Answer (score 3):

in Android studio 2.3.2
Sdk manager is Deleted !

So For access , you Can Test This Directory :
**Tools > Android > SDK Manager** !

after That You Have SDK Platform , SDK Tools , ..
Tabs ..

You Should Click On Show Package Details .
So Yo Can access To All Packages You Needs ..
See The Photo

Good Luck :)

[image: screenshot SDK Manager]

Answer (score 0):

download android SDK from external site [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

extract it  and configure a path to android studio using SDK Manager

refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#adding-sites) for more details